# scaling down the imarinary parts of eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, control-theory

Let **A** be an n-by-n complex matrix. Is there a transformation to preserve the real parts of the eigenvalues of **A** but scale down the imaginary parts of the eigenvalues of **A**? Actually , I want to have a matrix that keeps the real parts of the eigenvalues of the original matrix but have the sum of absolute of the imaginary parts of the original eigenvalues minimized or reduced.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by "transformation".

For instance, you can use the expression $$B=\dfrac{1}{2}P(J+\bar J)P^{-1}$$ where $A=PJP^{-1}$ and $J$ is the Jordan form of $A$ and $\bar J$ is the complex conjugate of $J$ (componentwise).

In this case, $B$ will have real eigenvalues which are equal to the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$.

An interesting point of this transformation is that it preserves the structure of the matrix by keeping its eigenvectors and its Jordan structure. Only the eigenvalues are changed.

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer helped me!

Comment: I have another question please. By Jordan decomposition, we have actually computed the eigenvalues of matrix A. Is there a way to do what I meant without calculating the eigenvalues of A?

Comment: @Mathisfreedom I need to think about it. Why are trying to find such a transformation?

Comment: I have designed a controller. If I remove imaginary parts, its response would become oscillarion-free

Comment: @Mathisfreedom So it is not only about matrix analysis but control theory. In this case, ask a proper question about control theory and use the relevant tags. Please provide all the necessary information in your post.

Comment: @Mathisfreedom Can you give more context about the control problem in the question? Depending on what it is, some solutions may be preferable to the others. In control problems, one cannot do whatever we want with the matrices of the system.